# Exclude specific endpoints from New Relic alert policies

Tags: spring, devops, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a Spring Boot web service that has multiple endpoints. Our policies in the NewRelic for the web service include the following rules:

- Response time (web) > 2 secs for at least 5 mins
- Response time (background) > 0.10 secs for at least 5 mins
- Response time (web) > 0.10 secs for at least 5 mins

Some of the endpoints are scheduled using Kubernetes CronJob and those endpoints have high response times.

I would like to exclude these specific endpoints from the NewRelic policies. I have checked the following documentations but could not find and answer:

[https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/advanced-[…]/rest-api-alerts/disable-enable-alerts-conditions-using-api/](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/advanced-%5B%E2%80%A6%5D/rest-api-alerts/disable-enable-alerts-conditions-using-api/)

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/advanced-alerts/rest-api-alerts/rest-api-calls-alerts/

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/api-guides/ignoring-specific-transactions/

Is there a way to exclude endpoints from NewRelic alert policies?

Comment: Are you able to find a solution @hakansander?